Не удается добавить подключение к Microsoft SQL из Visual Studio
К серверу в самом sql management получается подключится без каких либо проблем,но в ВС никак.(Прошу, помогите!
Перерыл все, но ничего нет.

Что пробовали? Что не получилось? Может ошибки есть? Добавьте больше информации в сам вопрос

пробовал в sql server manager включать tpc\ip протокол,
так же добавлял новый порт  1433 в исключение
естественно отключал брэендмауэр и безопсаность винды
это все что нашел, по данной теме

проблема решена, 2 часа прожиты напрасно. решение простое до ужаса: в пункте шифровать,нужно поставить Optional (False)
